# JQM footer issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

This is doing my head in.  I have a footer with various navigation buttons like so:

```
<div data-role = "footer" data-position = "fixed" data-theme = "b" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href= "example.html" rel="external" data-icon="home" data-iconpos = "notext"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="example2.html" rel="external" data-icon="info" data-iconpos = "notext"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="example3.html" rel="external" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos = "notext"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

On the simulator this all works perfectly no problem.  However on a device, when the keyboard opens, the footer goes above the keyboard for a split second and then returns back down, sometimes causing missclicks on the navbuttons.  I am using jquery mobile 1.4.2, so I'm wondering whether there is a fix to this.

Note:  the footer doesn't stay above the keyboard for the duration of the keyboard input, it just appears above it when the keyboard opens for around a second and then disappears.

EDIT:  I have seen all the solutions about hiding the footer when a textarea is in focus etc but none of them seem to be working for me.

EDIT:  The device is an iPhone 4 and an iPad mini, not sure of these details are needed

EDIT:  In response to the people that have commented, I have tried to make a jsfiddle recreating the problem, however I have been unable to do so.  Here is the problem on an iPhone 4:

[image: The footer stays there for a second then disappears when that input box is clicked]

Comment: Do you have a demo I can review?

Comment: I've tried recreating this on a simulator or browser, but it only happens on devices

similar to this problem:  http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-set-footer-fixed-at-bottom-even-if-virtual-keyboard-is-open

except, the footer moves back down after a second

Comment: Please put a demo together on jsfiddle and confirm that the issue exists in the devices you've tested, then we can take a look.

Comment: I couldn't produce this issue on iPhone 5. There should be many ways to fix it, but since I'm unable to reproduce the problem, I can't provide you with a definite solution. Can you confirm this issue on iPhone 5 - Safari or Chrome mobile?

Comment: I don't have access to an iPhone 5, sorry.  At this point, I'll take any ideas you may have.  Are you positive you are using the same 1.4.2 JQM version?

Comment: Yes, jQM 1.4.2 jQuery 1.9. Tested on both Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Well, regardless, the main goal here is to keep that footer at the bottom no matter what happens.  data-position = "fixed" isn't working so even alternatives to this that work would be great.  Kind of desperate with this now as this is the only bug left

Comment: try code here http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/RrMTB/ this would lead to a solution.

Comment: tested on laptop with Chrome and I can see that it is working, but on my iPhone it almost seems like the footer doesn't disappear quick enough.  It drags up above the keyboard for a very brief instance and then disappears.  Maybe it's because it's an old phone? (iPhone 4) and the processor isn't as quick as the iPhone 5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54710/discussion-between-omar-and-mohd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone interested, I finally found the answer.  It was through my own error, I didn't include: `height = device-height` in the code below.  This goes in the head of my HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = no, initial-scale = 1, maximum-scale = 1, minimum-scale=1, width = device-width, target-densitydpi = device-dpi height = device-height"/>
```